# Jquery +/- symbold to update cart quantity. How to auto-submit form after increment?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to auto submit, so the cart updates without having to press an "update cart" button. I have this working when the user manually types in a quantity with the following script:

```
$(function() {
$(".auto_submit_form").change(function() {
this.submit();
});
});
```

I also have plus and minus symbols that work great to update the quantity field, but I can't seem to get it to submit after updating the increment. Help!

This is the script I'm using for the plus and minus increment:

```
$(".ddd").on("click", function () {

var $button = $(this);
var oldValue = $button.closest('.sp-quantity').find("input.form-control").val();

if ($button.text() == "+") {
    var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) + 1;
    $( ".auto_submit_form" ).delay(60000).submit();
} else {
    // Don't allow decrementing below zero
    if (oldValue > 0) {
        var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) - 1;
      $( ".auto_submit_form" ).delay(60000).submit();
    } else {
        newVal = 0;
    }
}

$button.closest('.sp-quantity').find("input.form-control").val(newVal);
});
```

codepen:https://codepen.io/brandotron/pen/WyweKQ

Comment: Why are you delaying for a whole minute? Also, does it work if you just put the "submit()" call immediately after setting the new value for $button?

Comment: I was trying to delay it to give it time to process the update, but not only does it not delay--it doesn't even recognize that the number increments.

Currently when I press the + or -, it increments the field, submits the form, but still reflects the old value before the increment. Thanks for looking at it.

Comment: I'm afraid not much can be done without seeing some HTML also. A snippet that reproduces the problem would be resolved much faster. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Edited to include codepen:https://codepen.io/brandotron/pen/WyweKQ

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: I moved the auto submit to after the if/else and it works.